# FaultTypes in SoapUI

Tags: wsdl, soapui

SoapUI project created by using WSDL.. with definitions for Faults with complex types

```
<xsd:element name="Fault" type="FaultType">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>  </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
```

In Mock Response edit window, when I create a Fault response, it prompts to choose the fault name "fault" which is defined in the WSDL...

and it generates following soap fault message

```
  <faultcode>?</faultcode>
  <faultstring xml:lang=""></faultstring>
  <!--Optional:-->
  <faultactor>?</faultactor>
  <!--Optional:-->
  <detail>
    <com:Fault/>
    <!--You may enter ANY elements at this point-->
  </detail>
</soapenv:Fault>
```

i was expecting the complex elements as defined in schema in this response ...
did i miss something? or do i need to manually recreate this fault response

Kind Regards,
carya

Comment: You need to add an empty row before and after your code for it to show properly. Otherwise XML tags are not shown at all. I fixed it for you this time :-)

Comment: thanks for that... and sorry... i actually removed the xml tags.. as it was not showing properly..

Answer (score 0):

This is a little dated, but:

```
<xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:documentation>  </xsd:documentation>
</xsd:annotation>
```

Those are part of the specification as comments. There are tools that can parse the WSDL and show those to you as documentation for the WSDL; SoapUI is not one of those tools.

They are certainly not meant to be part of the message payload. What you are seeing is working as expected! You can have a read through the [official docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/sawsdl-guide/).